my cat had to go to work with me and now he's mad at me
So my cat ate something he shouldn't have so I brought him to work (I work at a vet clinic) to get hopefully get him take care of. He ended needing to go back again a week later both times he was there all day and I know he was super stressed about it.
I understand he may associate me with the vet office but he's been very pissy lately. However he still sleeps with me and greets me when I get home but when I try and engage with him he just gets angry.
I'm not sure what to do here. When he gets pissy I usually just walk away and when he gets kind of silly I try and play with him but then he just gets mad but I'm typing this now and he's sleeping on my legs like he usually does so like?????????
It's only been just over a week since his last visit and less than that when I stopped medicating him.
Should I just keep giving him space till he stops getting mad I just happen to exist in his space?

What behavior are you seeing that you are categorizing as "being mad" or "being pissy?" Cat emotions absolutely exist, but they work slightly differently than human emotions, so the answer depends heavily on the specific behavior that you are seeing and how it varies from how he normally is

He grumbles, tail lashes, he does this thing I call the "No Paw" because you're doing something he wants you to stop he usually does it a few times before he hisses but he barely dies it once before hissing, air plane ears, contracted pupils. Hes a tad grumpy generally (older cat, doesn't like when naps are interrupted/food is late type of grumpy) but it's like the dial went from 2 to 50. He's quick to change over to this angry behavior

Sounds like he's simply stressed and needs more time to settle down again. Last time you had to bring him back after a week, so it doesn't surprise me that this time he's still weary after a week. I think it's best to give him space whenever he doesn't want your interaction, but treat him as normal and welcoming as possible whenever he seeks you out for cuddling etc.

@Elmy: that looks like an Answer to me...
